# JS id element within table <th>

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

I am trying to produce a table which has a heading:
*Summary Statement as at Aug 3 2017 12:55*

The date using js works elsewhere, but not in this . Is there a trick to this? I am using a php/mysql query to get the rest of the data.

```
echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-nonfluid'>";
    echo "<thead>";   
       echo "<tr>";
         echo "<th colspan ='2'>Summary Statement as at <span id= "date"></span></th>";
     echo "</tr>";
```

JS:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = Date().slice(3,25);
</script>
```

Amended:

```
echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-nonfluid'>";
     echo "<thead>";   
       echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th colspan ='2'>Summary Statement as at <span id='date'></span></th>";
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "<thead>";
             echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<th>Payments</th>";
                 echo "<th>Amount (R)</th>";
                 echo "</tr>";
   echo "</thead>";
   echo "<tbody>";
   while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
       echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong quotes around the id attribute. I typically use ' for outers and " for inners. Try changing the quotes around your date to single quotes.

Comment: My table heading shows 'Summary Statement as at       ' after doing this. Doesn't seem to show the date.

Comment: Can you show the amended code and hopefully we can work this out.

Comment: What does the issue seem to be now then exactly? If you've amended the quotes the markup should be fine. What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
 echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-nonfluid'>";
        echo "<thead>";   
           echo "<tr>";
             echo "<th colspan ='2'>Summary Statement as at <span id= 'date'></span></th>";
         echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: same as for answer below

Comment: just example it

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing the line wrong :)
     echo "Summary Statement as at ";

since span id is part of echo, it should have '' quotes instead of "", just like colspan attribute.

Comment: Would you mind correcting the code and showing it in your answer? I don't see exactly what you mean...